# Android Imagemap with webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make an image map similar to [AndroidImageMap](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap). Now, i need to know whether the same implementation with android webview is possible? Because, the image map can be processed in the server side and implemented as HTML image map. If we use to display the HTML image map's URL in a webview, then how can the click events be recognized from the webview co-ordinates clicked?

Note : I need to perform respected action when the corresponding image map co-ordinates clicked.